# Test suite failed to run TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: angular, jestjs

I encountered a mysterious bug while executing tests in Angular using jest.

It reads

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
> |     property 'element' -> object with constructor 'Object'
> |     property 'componentProvider' -> object with constructor 'Object'
> --- property 'parent' closes the circle
> at stringify ()

or some variation of that error.

I found a fix for this, look at the answer below.

Comment: can you share your TestBad config?

Comment: @VadimB I updated my answer, see below. Hope it helps

Comment: The question should have the problematic code as a [mcve], the answer should have a possible fix. Even though you're trying to write a self-answer, the question should still abide by the normal quality standards. Otherwise nobody else can really contribute. See also: [Angular FormControl Jest test causing TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376613/angular-formcontrol-jest-test-causing-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-t)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that this is some kind of internal jest error.
After reading about similar issues on the [jestjs Github page](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10577), I managed to find following fix/workaround:

2. Run `npm run test:detectOpenHandles` or the equivalent `jest --detectOpenHandles`
3. Error now reads

> Found the synthetic listener @transform.start. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.

OR

> Found the synthetic property @transitionMessages. Please include[...]

4. To fix, import `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` in your test

I don't know what the above errors are caused by though. Hopefully this helps.

EDIT: Here is an example TestBed configuration from my current project:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppBarComponent } from './components/app-bar/app-bar.component';
import { SideNavComponent } from './components/side-nav/side-nav.component';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from './modules/angular-material.module';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        AngularMaterialModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AppBarComponent,
        SideNavComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: do you really need `async` in TestBed config?

Comment: @VadimB yes the `compileComponents` method is asynchronous. If you don't await it then your test will start running before the components are ready.